# "Characteristic" as an adjective to describe changes in a character

Tags: adjectives

Can the word `characteristic` be used to describe changes that occur to a character (I.E. a character in a film)?

For example:

```
... this foreshadows the changes to come - both plot and characteristic changes.
```

Where `characteristic changes` is referring to changes in a character's personality or perspective.

Would it be better to say `plot and character changes`?

Comment: Definitely. I'm not sure *characteristic* could ever mean *relating to a [fictional] character or characters*. Certainly people don't normally interpret it that way. Just use the noun form (familiar alongside "plot") as an adjective and all will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a definition in my dictionary that says that *characteristic* can mean *pertaining to characters in a story*. There is one definition that reads

> Relating to or descriptive of [moral] character.

so I suppose you could use it if the changes fit that usage of the word *character*. You could also use it if you were trying to make some sort of pun. It doesn't look like either of these is the case from your example, however.

Even if there were such a definition, I would say that your idea to use "plot and character changes" is a good one. That way, you avoid forcing your readers to re-parse the sentence with a different meaning of *characteristic* in mind.